# Where is the Oberon syntax not LL(1)?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

7.2. Where is the Oberon syntax not LL(1), that is, where is a lookahead of more than one symbol
necessary? Change the syntax in such a way that it satisfies the LL(1) property
Here is Oberon syntax:

```
ident = letter {letter | digit}.
integer = digit {digit}.
selector = {"." ident | "[" expression "]"}.
number = integer.
factor = ident selector | number | "(" expression ")" | "~" factor.
term = factor {("*" | "DIV" | "MOD" | "&") factor}.
SimpleExpression = ["+"|"-"] term {("+"|"-" | "OR") term}.
expression = SimpleExpression
[("=" | "#" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">=") SimpleExpression].
assignment = ident selector ":=" expression.
ActualParameters = "(" [expression {"," expression}] ")" .
ProcedureCall = ident selector [ActualParameters].
IfStatement = "IF" expression "THEN" StatementSequence
{"ELSIF" expression "THEN" StatementSequence}
["ELSE" StatementSequence] "END".
WhileStatement = "WHILE" expression "DO" StatementSequence "END".
statement = [assignment | ProcedureCall | IfStatement | WhileStatement].
StatementSequence = statement {";" statement}.
IdentList = ident {"," ident}.
ArrayType = "ARRAY" expression "OF" type.
FieldList = [IdentList ":" type].
RecordType = "RECORD" FieldList {";" FieldList} "END".
type = ident | ArrayType | RecordType.
FPSection = ["VAR"] IdentList ":" type.
FormalParameters = "(" [FPSection {";" FPSection}] ")".
ProcedureHeading = "PROCEDURE" ident [FormalParameters].
ProcedureBody = declarations ["BEGIN" StatementSequence] "END" ident.
ProcedureDeclaration = ProcedureHeading ";" ProcedureBody.
declarations = ["CONST" {ident "=" expression ";"}]
["TYPE" {ident "=" type ";"}]
["VAR" {IdentList ":" type ";"}]
{ProcedureDeclaration ";"}.
module = "MODULE" ident ";" declarations
["BEGIN" StatementSequence] "END" ident "." .
```

Comment: Is this by any chance homework?

Comment: I usually don't ask questions where I know the answer, but: is this homework?

Comment: No it isnt.I just downloaded  book about compilers and i am trying to read it.

Comment: Well, if it's (self) education, surely you learn more by doing it yourself, or trying to do it yourself. Perhaps you _did_ try yourself, but that doesn't show by the way you asked your question. So, have you  any idea which of these rules contains (sub) rules that need more than 1 look-ahead?

Comment: I suspect ident selector but how am i going to change it?

Comment: yes but i was thinking that every ident selector is unique

Comment: Not sure what you mean by these 2 last comments. When the parser comes into `statement` and the next token in line is an `ident`, "it" doesn't know which of the rules to choose: `assignment` or `ProcedureCall`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're right: a `statement` can be an `assignment` or a `ProcedureCall` of which both start with the rules `ident selector`:

```
assignment = ident selector ":=" expression.
ProcedureCall = ident selector [ActualParameters].
statement = [assignment | ProcedureCall | IfStatement | WhileStatement].
```

You can make it LL(1) by removing `assignment` and `ProcedureCall` and changing `statement` into:

```
statement 
 = [ ident selector (":=" expression | [ActualParameters]) 
   | IfStatement 
   | WhileStatement
   ]
 .
```

(not sure if this will affect other rules in your grammar, but you hopefully get the idea how to make it LL(1))